# use CancelColor in mathjax

Tags: mathjax

I want to use `\cancel{·}` in mathjax. with a crossed line of different color, explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105902/cancel-with-different-colors).

I use

```
\[
enter code here
\require{xcolor}
\require{cancel}
\renewcommand\CancelColor{\color{red}}

\cancel{x^2}
\]
```

But is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for future references, a good answer was given in tex Stack Exchange
[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417734/use-cancelcolor-in-mathjax/417945#417945)